# Why tbb::concurrent_hash_map is slower than std::unordered_map in term of wirte and read despite using tbb::parallel_for? Especially read time

Tags: c++, hashtable

Time used:

```
std::unordered_map time：267ms
-------------------find time：55ms

 tbb::concurrent_hash_map tbb parrallel time：295ms
 -------------------find time：235ms
```

Here is the code:

```
    const int kNumElements = 10'000'000;
    // TODO: 1. test unordered_map
    std::unordered_map<int, int> map_int_unordered(kNumElements);
    auto start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < kNumElements; i++)
    {
        map_int_unordered[i] = i;
    }
    auto end_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time);
    std::cout << DEBUG << "1. std::unordered_map time：" << duration.count() << "ms" << std::endl;
    // print_map(map_int_unordered);

    start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < kNumElements; i++)
    {
        map_int_unordered.find(i);
    }
    end_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time);
    std::cout << GREEN << " -------------------find time：" << duration.count() << "ms" << std::endl;
```

```
    tbb::concurrent_hash_map<int, int> map_tbb2(kNumElements);
    start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    tbb::parallel_for(0, kNumElements, [&](int i)
                      { map_tbb2.insert(std::make_pair(i, i)); });
    end_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time);
    std::cout << DEBUG << "3. tbb::concurrent_hash_map tbb parrallel time：" << duration.count() << "ms" << std::endl;

    start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    tbb::parallel_for(0, kNumElements, [&](int i)
                      {  
                        tbb::concurrent_hash_map<int, int>::accessor acc;
                        map.find(acc,i); });
    end_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time);
    std::cout << GREEN << " -------------------find time：" << duration.count() << "ms" << std::endl;
```

Is there any faster than std::unordered_map? I have tried ankerl/unordered_dense, tsl/robin_map.

Here is the result:

```
 tsl::robin_map time：224ms
 -------------------find time：21ms
 tsl::robin_map multi-threads time：133ms
    -------------------find time：17ms
 ankerl::unordered_dense::map time：338ms
 -------------------find time：270ms
```

Although tsl::robin_map is faster, when I used it in my self-defined class, it become very slow.

Comment: fwiw [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) "The high_resolution_clock is not implemented consistently across different standard library implementations, and its use should be avoided." usually its ok to use it, until it isnt and then you wish you had used the proper ;) The big bummer is that it is not necessarily monotonic, and then its really useless to measure time with high accuracy

Comment: What's `kNumElements`?

Comment: Sorry, `kNumElements` is the number of inserted elements.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. It has been modified to `steady_clock`. @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: how did you compile ? did you turn on compiler optimizations?

Comment: i am not so much into hash maps, but using bucket count equal to number of elements to be inserted doesnt look right.

Comment: Yeah, i have turned on -O3 compiler optimizations. The initialization of the bucket count may be related to the load factor, though I set it to twice the number, the result is similar.

Comment: Many factors affect how different hash table implementations perform: reserving space for buckets up-front to minimise resizing/rehashing during insertions, load factor, the hash function used (very important, especially for power-of-2 bucket counts), and some open addressing implementations let you choose whether to use additional data or sentinel values of the Key type to track unused and "tombstone" buckets.  For separate-chaining a load factor of 1 is fine, as colliding elements are in a list outside the buckets; otherwise benchmark 1.2-2: too small = collisions; too big = cache misses.